# PMP question bank

Tags: pmp

I am looking for a way to practice for PMP. A question bank for PMP would be nice. There are lots of sample questions in web. But I do not know which one to select. What can be the criteria to select? Or do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Check out Rita's PMP exam prep. I experienced a quite similar level of difficulty as during the exam

Comment: This question is a search/shopping question, and as such is off-topic for the site. Please feel free to improve your question in accordance with the guidance in our help center, or the question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

PMI does not publish its bank of questions.  So you will not find it.  Anything you find on the web, whether it is from a PMI-approved supplier or not, are their own questions and may or may not represent PMI's test.  Personally, I found the practice questions to be significantly harder than the test itself, which I induced was a marketing ploy to sell their training boot camps.  I cannot prove that, though, just my opinion.